# How to apply different background images for each page using PerlTeX

Tags: graphics

How do I apply a different background image for each page? I have an array of pdf's to apply. I have used the watermark package. However, I do not like the idea of manually adding a different watermark for hundreds of pages, I prefer the idea of using perltex --love Perl! I guess the question is really, how do I access each page's data structure, just before it is written to a file?

Here is the perl code I have created so far:

```
\def\numbpgs{\getpagerefnumber{LastPage}}
\def\imgs{1 2 3 ... x}
\bkgrndimages{\numbpgs}{\imgs}

\perlnewcommand{\bkgrndimages}[2]{

  my $numpgs = $_[0];
  my @imgarray = split / /, $_[1];
  my $return = ();

  my $c = 1;
  for (0 .. $numpgs) {
    # Here I wish to modify each page's background to 
    $return .= WATERMARK[LATEXPAGE[$c]] $imgarray[$c]\.pdf;
    $c++;
  }
  return $return;
 }
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx). If you select your code and click `{}` button or press Ctrl-K the code is displayed correctly. (or you can introduce 4 whitespace characters at the beginning of each line manually)

Comment: Did you look at the package `atbegshi`?

Answer (score 2):

I think your love for Perl is making you take the wrong path.

> how do I access each page's data structure, just before it is written
>   to a file?

This is normally done using one of the packages `atbegshi`, `bophook`, `everyshi`, `eso-pic` or `\background`  The packages will enable you to hook into LaTeX's output routine and add a picture or text before shipment.

If all the documents use the same class, it is also possible to hook into every page using the header. This is my preferred way and here is a MWE as to how to do it.

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{lipsum,xcolor}
%\IfFileExists{changepage.sty}{%
%  \PassOptionsToPackage{strict}{changepage}
%  \RequirePackage{changepage}
%  }{}
\IfFileExists{rotating.sty}{\RequirePackage{rotating}}{}
\makeatletter
\def\even@samplepage{%
 \begin{picture}(0,0)
   \put(\Xeven,\Yeven){\turnbox{90}{\Huge \textcolor{\watermark@textcolor}{\watermark@text}}}
\end{picture}
}
%% Define a macro to print SAMPLE PAGE IN THE MARGIN
\def\odd@samplepage{%
 \begin{picture}(0,0)
   \put(\Xodd,\Yodd){\turnbox{90}{\Huge \textcolor{\watermark@textcolor}{\watermark@text}}}
 \end{picture}
}
%  Define the watermark words
\def\watermarktext#1{\gdef\watermark@text{\fontfamily{phv}\selectfont#1}}
\def\watermarktextcolor#1{\gdef\watermark@textcolor{#1}}
% redefine headings
\def\ps@samplepage{\let\@mkboth\@gobbletwo
 \let\@oddhead\odd@samplepage\def\@oddfoot{\reset@font\hfil\thepage}
 \let\@evenhead\even@samplepage\def\@evenfoot{\reset@font\thepage\hfil}}
%%
%% We define two macros to position the watermark on the page
\def\Xodd{500}
\def\Xeven{-70}\def\Yeven{-810}
\def\Yeven{-\expandafter\strip@pt\textheight}
\let\Yodd\Yeven
\watermarktext{SAMPLE PAGE}
\watermarktextcolor{blue}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\pagestyle{samplepage}
\lipsum
\end{document}

% end of document
```

Comment: The MWE does not solve the question, which specifically asks about setting a different background for each page

Comment: @Damaru I think you missed the point. Now this was in 2012! Now you can use other methods as well. LaTeX3 or TikZ